# When i try update a column it's update 2 unit

Tags: php, database, pdo, sql-update

When i try to update a column +1 unit, it's increasing +2 unit.

My code :

```
//For example $str['y'] = 1

$lastValue = $str['y'] + 1;
$update = $vt->prepare("UPDATE contents SET y = :y WHERE id = :id");
$update->bindParam(':id',$str['id'] ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->bindParam(':y',$lastValue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute();
```

And i try this way :

```
$update = $vt->prepare("UPDATE contents SET y = y + 1 WHERE id = :id");
$update->bindParam(':id',$str['id'] ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute();
```

So, in my database column "y" must be increase 1 but it's increasing 2 at the moment. And i'm sure it's not in any loop.

EDIT : when i open ini_set('display_errors', 'On');error_reporting(E_ALL); it's work normal. ( it's increase just 1)

Comment: may be query executes twice?

Comment: ok. try next: `$update->execute(); die();` and check db.

Comment: try with  $lastValue = $str['y']++ insted of  $lastValue = $str['y'] + 1;

Comment: @DanilaHanchar  query executes just once and  i've try but it's same.. :(

Comment: @IshanShah i've try but it's same.. :(

Comment: can you please print the query which is execute?

Comment: @IshanShah That won't work. The value of `$str['y']++` is the value from **before** the variable is incremented.

Comment: @IshanShah And why would you need to change the value in the array anyway?

Comment: Check you PHP log, make sure the script isn't being run twice. Another thing to look for is a trigger that updates the column.

Comment: @IshanShah sorry, i dont understand. My executed query is in up

Comment: @user1719993 are you sure that query `UPDATE contents SET y = y + 1 WHERE id = :id` increasing 2 value of **y**?

Comment: @DanilaHanchar yes, i'm check on PHP myadmin

Comment: @user1719993 ok. run query in phpadmin `UPDATE contents SET y = y + 1 WHERE id =your_id` and check result. What do you see?

Comment: @DanilaHanchar yes, it's work on Phpadmin, but not working on PHP. And here my full code : http://paste.ofcode.org/YH5ts4juaRZSeNmaetN7sa  update block on line 58.

Comment: For debugging: Could you put an `echo 'X';` directly behind your `execute`statement and check how many Xs are printed?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user just one.. i'm gonna be insane. It should not be difficult.

Comment: It really shouldn't. You're pastebin code doesn't enlighten me either... Could you show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`, maybe?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user here table structure http://paste.ofcode.org/XMWanWXp8HfRG62MF5HDLt

Comment: @user1719993 try to comment rows `$commentSql = $vt->prepare($feSql); $commentSql->execute(array(':iid' => $str['id']));` and all **foreach** . I mean rows from 90 to 106.
    `

Comment: @Danila Hanchar: good point. Where does `$feSql` come from, anyway? It doesn't seem to be initialised. @user1719993 can you elaborate on that variable, plz?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I'm sure that php call update query twice.

Comment: @DanilaHanchar i removed all $commentSql and all sub func. still same increase 2 :(

Comment: @some-non-descript-user `$feSql = "SELECT users.id,users.name, comment.c_id,comment.u_id,comment.date,comment.comment FROM users LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.us_id = users.id WHERE comment.c_id = :iid AND comment.approve !=0 ORDER BY comment.date DESC" `

Comment: @user1719993 ok. I think exists 2 ways to solve problem. First - configure [debugger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+Debugger), set breakpoint to 59 line and look for problems(it is more easy way). Second - add comment to all source except `UPDATE contents SET y = y + 1`.... We see that query is good... Try uncommented source step by step and look why query performed twice.

Comment: Hi again guys,
@ DanilaHanchar, i choose the hard way (second).  i've add comments all code step by step ( even tag by tag ), and i didn't find what is the problem. 
And i solve with ajax.. Any way thanks for helping guys. @some-non-descript-user and all commentator..

Comment: @user1719993 I'm sure that php executes query twice.Try this in test.php: `$pdo = new PDO(params...);
$update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE contents SET y = y + 1 WHERE id = id_row_for_test");
$update->execute();`. You make sure that the bug is not in the query, but in logic.